# In a React Component, where should I bind arguments to my onClick functions?

Tags: reactjs

So in an example component

`<Button doStuff={doStuff} />`

I know this is bad, it creates a new function on every render:

```
class Button extends Component {
  const value = getClickValue(this.props); // do something with props 
  render() {
    <button onClick={() => this.props.doStuff(value)}>Click me</button>
  }
}
```

But not sure which is better for performance from the following:

1) Bind click value in a class property function

This is a trivial example, but in my current component the code to process the props is cluttering my component up and makes the component more smart and less dumb, when you want to strive to have DUMB components and smart containers.

```
class Button extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const value = getClickValue(this.props); // do something with props to get value
    this.props.doStuff(value);
  }

  render() {
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
  }
}
```

2) Send bound functions as props from a container to a stateless functional component.

This method seems better from an organizational perspective. The component is as dumb as possible and is only concerned with rendering. But does it impact performance? As in, is a new function constructed every time the `ownProps` changes?

```
const Button = (onClick) => (
  <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click me!</button>
)

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  const value = getClickValue(ownProps);
  return {
    onClick: () => doStuff(value)
  };
};

connect(null, mapDispatchToprops)(Button);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second approach, every time your props change, `mapDispatchToProps` is called. Since you're returning an arrow function, it will create that function again.

That makes your first suggestion the best option.